# Ignition.Start() is not picking the default config from {IGNITEHOME}/config/default-config.xml and error on starting the server with config file name

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Two strange issues when using Apache Ignite.NET

1. `Ignition.Start()` method is not picking the default config file path from `{IGNITEHOME}/config/default-config.xml` instead using all system defaults.
2. Getting an error while specifying the default config file path but server start successfully without config file path (`Ignition.Start()`).

Below is the simple code, logg and config file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("IGNITE_HOME=" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IGNITE_HOME"));


     var ignite = Ignition.Start(@"C:/Apache/gridgain-community-8.8.16/config/default-config.xml");
    //var ignite = Ignition.Start();
    var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>("my-cache");
    cache.Put(1, "Hello, World");
    Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(1));
}
```

The main error

```
[14:56:12,518][INFO][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=/127.0.0.1, port=11211]
[14:56:12,558][WARNING][main][PlatformProcessorImpl] Marshaller is automatically set to o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryMarshaller (other nodes must have the same marshaller type).
[14:56:12,606][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%Justin Local Grid] **Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Invalid header on deserialization. Expected: 9 but was: 119**
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackUtils.inLongLongLongObjectOutLong(Native Method)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackGateway.onStart(PlatformCallbackGateway.java:837)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformProcessorImpl.start(PlatformProcessorImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1908)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1177)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1784)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1706)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1143)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:634)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.start(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:45)
```

Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
 Copyright 2019 GridGain Systems, Inc. and Contributors.

 Licensed under the GridGain Community Edition License (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     https://www.gridgain.com/products/software/community-edition/gridgain-community-edition-license

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="localHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <property name="gridName" value="Justin Local Grid"/>
         <property name="workDirectory" value="C:\Apache\gridgain-community-8.8.16\work"/>  
        <property name="userAttributes">
            <map>
                <entry key="my_attr" value="value1"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="socketTimeout" value="300" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invalid header on deserialization` is caused by a mismatch between .NET and Java parts of Apache Ignite.

1. Do a clean rebuild (delete `bin` and `obj` directories from your project). Old jar files get stuck there sometimes when switching from Ignite to GridGain and/or between different versions of Ignite/GridGain.
2. `IGNITE_HOME` environment variable is NOT needed when using Ignite.NET from NuGet, remove it from the system. It is needed only for custom deployments. See https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-deployment-options#custom-deployment

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I still have the same issue after doing clean build and also deleting bin and obj folder.

I've also removed IGNITE_HOME environment variable.

But still Ignition.Start(); is working without any issues , 

The error happening only when the config file is mentioned in the start method 

the error "[00:02:17,897][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%Justin Local Grid] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Invalid header on deserialization. Expected: 9 but was: 119"

Comment: Can you try removing all child elements of `<bean id="grid.cfg" ..` config element?

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thank you very much. I hope for me the 2nd step: deleting IGNITE_HOME environment variable Is worked. But, please note , I’ve to re-start the machine(windows 10) to take effect of removing the environment variable and happily all works now.